# Pivotal Cloud Foundry vs. VMware Tanzu Application Service

Tags: cloud, cloud-foundry, vmware, tanzu-application-service

Pivotal Cloud Foundry(PCF) vs VMware Tanzu Application Service: Which is better? Are they same? Or did the name just get changed? Or is it just an upgrade and can older applications on PCF be upgraded to Tanzu?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pivotal was acquired by VMware at the beginning of 2020, the branding switched so that formerly labelled Pivotal products are now under the Tanzu name. VMware continues to develop this software under the Tanzu brand. Pivotal’s offerings are core to the VMware Tanzu portfolio of products and services.

In short; Pivotal Cloud Foundry (PCF) was purchased by VMWare and renamed to Tanzu Application Service (TAS). Harness has not updated its UI yet, and so you will see PCF and Pivotal Cloud Foundry used in Harness.