# Pivotal cloud foundry still used in 2023?

Tags: cloud, paas, pcf

Can anyone please tell me if pcf is still used in 2023 ?

Did some research & found that PCF has been renamed to TAS (Tanzu Application Service) after Pivotal got acquired by VMware.

Can anybody list the alternatives for PCF  being used in the industry.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes it's being used just many organizations
2. Kindly refer [Pivotal Cloud Foundry vs. VMware Tanzu Application Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67972330/pivotal-cloud-foundry-vs-vmware-tanzu-application-service?rq=2) for PCF and TAS
3. There are options like IBM bluemix, AWS elastic beanstalk, Salesforce Heroku, GCP, Alababa Cloud and Microsoft Azure etc